# Time without date

Tags: android, time, date, timeofday

I get time with time zone (without date component) from a PostgreSQL server in json like this `{ "time": "03:00:00+01" }`. How do I handle this in Android? Is there any structure which can hold just time without date? Or converting it to the epoch `Date` representation i.e. `Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970` is the only good solution?

Comment: There are some options. What do you need to with the time in Android? [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html) from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) may be the best class for representing the time, but it depends on your needs, so please tell us what they are.

Comment: I will point out that a time-of-day with an offset does not really have any meaning. Without the context of a date, the offset does no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### OffsetTime from java.time and ThreeTenABP

An `OffsetTime` is a time of day  without date and with an offset from UTC. It thus very precisely models the information in your string from JSON. So I would clearly prefer it over `Date`. Also because the `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated.

```
    String timeStringFromJson = "03:00:00+01";
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ssX");
    OffsetTime parsedTime = OffsetTime.parse(timeStringFromJson, timeFormatter);
    System.out.println("Parsed time: " + parsedTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Parsed time: 03:00+01:00

As a detail that may or may not matter to you, the offset from the string is retained, contrary to what `Date` can do because a `Date` hasn’t got a time zone or offset.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your date into a `Date` object using the `SimpleDateFormat` with the following pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

try
    {
    Date date = format.parse("03:00:00+01", Locale.getDefault());
    Log.d( "debugDate", " date is: " + date );
    }
catch (ParseException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970
```

In case your date structure become "03:00:00+01:00", you need to use this pattern :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
```

Output:

```
Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970
```

Comment: It still means converting it into a date dependent object.

Comment: Yes, this is not what you want?

Comment: No, this solution was mentioned in the question itself. I am looking for somthing which can handle time irrespective to date.

Comment: Consider not using the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I got `The method parse(String, ParsePosition) in the type SimpleDateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String, Locale)`. Correcting this I get the expected output in your time zone and in mine, but when I ran in America/Toronto time zone I got `date is: Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EST 1970`, which despite the similar look is a completely different point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the String timestamp to the milliseconds since Epoch as a `long` value, then store/retrieve the `long` value and convert it back to a String timestamp as done below in `main`.

I'm assuming the `+01` in your example is for Central European Time.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class SDFTest {

    /**
    Global SimpleDateFormat
    */
    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize the Simple Date Format;
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssX");
        // Ignore this if you need timestamps converted to your local TimeZone;
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));

        // Say this is the supplied time String;
        String suppliedDate = "03:00:00+01";

        // Convert from String timestamp to long;
        long convertedToTimeStamp = getTimeStamp(suppliedDate);
        System.out.println(suppliedDate + " => " + convertedToTimeStamp + "ms");

        // Convert from long timestamp to String;
        String convertedBackToString = getDateString(convertedToTimeStamp);
        System.out.println(convertedToTimeStamp + "ms => " + convertedBackToString);
    }


    /**
    Converts String timestamp to the number of milliseconds since Epoch.
    */
    private static long getTimeStamp(String date_str) {
        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(date_str);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
    Converts long timestamp to String
    */
    private static String getDateString(long timestamp) {
        try {
            Date date = new Date(timestamp);
            return sdf.format(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Output:

[image: Convert String timestamp to long and back]

As the Date component is not present in the `suppliedDate` it won't ever matter.